# Plugin not found error in Zend modular application

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I would like to make an application that Zend has the following structure:

```
-SITE
---- application
---- configs
---- layouts
---- modules
-------- default
------------ controllers
------------ forms
------------ models
------------ views
------------ Bootstrap.php
-------- admin
------------ controllers
------------ forms
------------ models
------------ views
------------ Bootstrap.php
---- Bootstrap.php
-- public
-- library
------My
---------Controller
-----------Plugin
-------------ModuleDispatch.php
------Zend
-- index.php
```

But I ran into problems reaching the admin module. I realized that perhaps my problem is routing and had implemented a written Plugin and the method preDispatch (). The name of Plugin is ModuleDispatch() and is in library/My/Controller/Plugin.

My application.ini file is:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.modules = ""


resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.plugins.moduleDispatch=ModuleDispatch

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

But when running, I always get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'ModuleDispatch' not found in
>   /var/www/study/library/Zend/Application/Resource/Frontcontroller.php
>   on line 117 Call Stack: 0.0916 334628 1. {main}()
>   /var/www/study/public/index.php:0 0.5735 1248652 2.
>   Zend_Application->bootstrap() /var/www/study/public/index.php:25
>   0.5735 1248696 3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
>   /var/www/study/library/Zend/Application.php:355 0.5735 1248696 4.
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
>   /var/www/study/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:586
>   0.6280 1282720 5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
>   /var/www/study/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:626
>   0.6280 1283088 6. Zend_Application_Resource_Frontcontroller->init() /var/www/study/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:683

What could be wrong?

Comment: You are encouraged to post the solution to a problem when you finally get it solved, but you should post it as an *answer* rather than including it as an edit to your question. I've done that for you here, but just something to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resources.frontController.plugins.moduleDispatch=ModuleDispatch
```

Should be:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.moduleDispatch = "My_Controller_Plugin_ModuleDispatch"
```

and that class needs to be named `My_Controller_Plugin_ModuleDispatch` (case sensitive). You will also need to have registered `My_` as a namespace with the autoloader.

Comment: I added in my fil application.ini the following lines:

autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
resources.frontController.plugins.moduleDispatch = "My_Controller_Plugin_ModuleDispatch"

I renamed the class and the file with the name:

My_Controller_Plugin_ModuleDispatch

But I get the following error

Warning: include_once(My/Controller/Plugin/ModuleDispatch.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: The rest of that error should show the include path it checked for the class. Does it show your library folder?

Comment: In what sense is there to indicate my library folder is visible? Allowed?

Comment: Try adding `autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"` to application.ini.

Comment: autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_" is already present in the file application.ini

Comment: So what problem are you still experiencing? It can't find the class?

Comment: The warning is:Warning: include_once(My/Controller/Plugin/ModuleDispatch.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/study/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Comment: The problem is that it can not find the file Plugins/ModuleDispatch.php. In fact, the warning is the following: Warning: include_once(Plugins/ModuleDispatch.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/study/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved it by modifying the `application.ini` file as follows:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"

autoloaderNamespaces.plugins = "Plugins_"
resources.frontController.plugins.moduleDispatch= "Plugins_ModuleDispatch"

resources.frontController.baseUrl=/baseUrlSite/


;DB CONFIGURATION

resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password" 
resources.db.params.dbname = "dbname"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```